# Xcode-perform Segue in main view controller from action in popover

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, segue, popover

I’m creating an an that requires either logging in or signing up. Both logging in and signing up are currently performed in popover views over the main logged out screen.

Thus I need to trigger a segue to be performed in a different view controller from my popover view controller. How and/or is this possible?

this is my registration code in my ‘registerViewController’(popover view) and I want to perform the segue from my ‘loggedOutViewController’ to my ‘mainViewController’ (logged in view).

registerViewController.m:

```
- (void) registerNewUser {

PFUser *newUser = [PFUser user];
newUser.email = _emailField.text;
newUser.username = _usernameField.text;
newUser.password= _passwordField.text;
newUser[@"name"] = _nameField.text;

[newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Registration Successful" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

        //Where I need to call the segue

    } else {
        NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];
```

Apologies if this been asked already, I could not find a solution to my problem anywhere, and if you would like/need anymore information or code please let me know.

Comment: Please show the problematic code. No code, no discussion. ;)

Comment: There’s not really problem code per se, as i have no real idea how to go about it. I’ll see what i can post though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know exactly what your desired behavior is.  Here is one method:

```
// Display settings view
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SettingsVC *report = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsViewController"];
[self presentViewController:report animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Replace story board and desired view controller name with your own.  Also, make sure your view controller is correct by replacing `SettingsVC` with the name of your desired view controller.

Comment: Thank you, the code you provided answered my question well. The behaviour your code describes almost perfectly matches my ideal behaviour. I really should have been able o work this out but I struggled. Thanks!